# No module named 'sklearn.externals.six'

Tags: python

```
# Import following modules and libraries to visualize the tree:

from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier, export_graphviz
from sklearn.externals.six import StrinIO
import pydotplus

dot_data = StringIO()
export_graphviz(dtc, out_file="mytree.dot",feature_names=col[1:27],filled=True,rounded=True,special_characters=True)
graph= pydotplus.graph_from_dot_data(dot_data.getvalue())
```

Answer (score 0):

[sklearn.externals.six is deprecated](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/whats_new/v0.21.html) You should be able to using StringIO by directly importing it from the module `six`:

```
from six import StringIO
```

As you did not provide an example to run the rest of your code, I don't know whether it will work